# What kind of website would benefit from an SSD powered hosting?

Tags: ssd, http, hosting, web-hosting

I've been hosting sites for quite sometime now on regular HDD servers, they pretty much do the job fast enough for me. I was wondering what kind of sites would typically benefit from SSD powered hosting where the performance will be noticeable?

Comment: Any website that uses the disk(s) as a resource. :)

Comment: Benefits to you as a host would be much lower power cost. Problems would be higher upfront cost and probably more frequent replacements.

Answer (score 1):

Websites with moredate or large demand.

Any disk could handle a few MB/s, which will top most broadband connections, so even large files would not impact an HDD-powered server, but serving different files for several simultaneous users (even small ones) would be the worst case scenario for an HDD, since it's read speed would be wasted going back and forth between the files.

Nevertheless, you could improve that in a HDD server by doing RAM cache (on modern Linux images the OS does the RAM cache of recently used files automatically), so it is possible that you would not have much improvement on your users' browsing experience.

Try monitoring disk activity on your server and check if has large I/O.

NOTE: starting a service on the server would be greatly improved if you employ a SSD, so you would expect lower downtimes during upgrades or maintenance.